# Как исправить Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var slides = ['<div id = '
  slide1 '>первый слайд<br><img src = '
  1. jpg '></div>',
  '<div id = '
  slide2 '>второй слайд<br><img src = '
  2. jpg '></div>',
  '<div id = '
  slide3 '>третий слайд<br><img src = '
  3. jpg '></div>'
];
var currentSlide = 0;
var numberOfSlides = slides.length - 1;
window.onload = loader;

function loader() {
  changeImage();
}

function changeImage() {
  if (currentSlide > numberOfSlides) {
    currentSlide = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('slideshow').innerHTML = slides[currentSlide];
  currentSlide++;
  setTimeout(changeImage, 1000);
}
```

```css
#slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  display: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id='slideshow'></div>
```

Рабочая программа должна показывать слайдшоу из трёх картинок, но почему-то в массиве "slides" возникает ошибка

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

хотя вроде бы всё должно работать.

Comment: Ну как бы да, `'<div id = 'slide1'>` это сплошной синтаксический бардак

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Экранировать надо `' "your-image" '` или слэшами обратными `' \' your-image \' '`, как то так:

```js
var slides = ['<div id = "slide1">первый слайд<br><img src = "//picsum.photos/200/300"></div>',
  '<div id = "  slide2 ">второй слайд<br><img src = "//picsum.photos/200/301"></div>',
  '<div id = "  slide3 ">третий слайд<br><img src = "//picsum.photos/200/302"></div>'
];
var currentSlide = 0;
var numberOfSlides = slides.length - 1;
window.onload = loader;

function loader() {
  changeImage();
}

function changeImage() {
  if (currentSlide > numberOfSlides) {
    currentSlide = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('slideshow').innerHTML = slides[currentSlide];
  currentSlide++;
  setTimeout(changeImage, 1000);
}
```

```css
#slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  display: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id='slideshow'></div>
```